# how to sync the bucketed item programatically in sitecore

Tags: content-editor, buckets

I was bucketing an item in Sitecore, and did some customizations it the folder structure also, I followed this link [custom buckets](https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/04/how-to-create-custom-item-bucket-rules-in-sitecore-cms/), and the bucket structure which is being created is based on the date field, but the issue is, what if I want to automate the sync of the bucket folder on the date field without manually going to Sitecore and sync the bucket item .

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple options for this based on your requirement. if you want to simply do it in the Sitecore you can use Item save event but if you want it in outside the sitecore client then you need to write your custom code to run

> BucketManager.Sync(bucketItem);

sample code for  item:saved event

```
public class ItemSavedEventHandler
{
    public void Execute(object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(sender, "sender is null");
        Assert.IsNotNull(args, "args is null");

        using (new EventDisabler())
        {
            var parameter = args.Item;

            if (!BucketManager.IsItemContainedWithinBucket(paremeter))
            {
                return;
            }

            var bucketItem = parameter.GetParentBucketItemOrParent();

            if (!bucketItem.IsABucket())
            {
                return;
            }

        BucketManager.Sync(bucketItem);
    }
  }
}
```

You need to create a custom configuration -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:saved">
        <handler type="XYZ.Events.ItemSavedHandler, XYZ" method="OnItemSaved">
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: where this method is called ?  do i have to use pipelines to call this method ?

Comment: you need to add a custom configuration for calling your handler on "item:saved" event. I have updated the answer for this.

Comment: ok thanks , will try this for sure , appreciate your help

Comment: `ItemSavedEventArgs` didn't work for me. `EventArgs` worked, however. Here's an example of what worked for me: https://naveed-ahmad.com/2011/11/02/sitecore-extending-onitemsave-handler/

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't recommend using an EventDisabler in conjunction with `BucketManager.Sync()`. Lots of potential issues there.