# How to organize bucketable items automatically without clicking the sync option every time after creating a bucketable item

Tags: buckets

I have changed the existing template to a 'bucketable item'. When I create a page using that template, I have to click the sync option to create that item in the correct bucket structure (otherwise it will create outside of the bucket structure). Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: You can create a handler for item:saved event which can trigger the sync automatedly. The answer in this link shall work in your case - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/how-to-sync-the-bucketed-item-programatically-in-sitecore

Comment: Thank you Ghanendra.